# How to change default NSIS logo and also add an shortcut to desktop?

Tags: installation, nsis

I tried changing my logo but the following error occurs:`!define: "MUI_INSERT_NSISCONF" already defined!`

I'm very new to NSIS.Sorry if this is a silly question for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a shortcut on a `Desktop` for the current user:

```
CreateShortCut "$DESKTOP\Filename.lnk" "$INSTDIR\SomeFile.exe" "<Optional Command Line>"
```

To change the icon and logo:

```
!include "MUI2.nsh"

!define MUI_ICON "MyApp.ico"
!define MUI_UNICON "MyApp.ico"
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_BITMAP "InstallerLogo.bmp"
```

Comment: Hi.Thanks for answering my question.The error keeps occurring.What i should do?

Comment: Where should i put CreateShortCut?

Comment: Please refer to this link for sample installer skeleton: https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Sample_installation_script_for_an_application

Comment: what should i do after i compiled my .nsi file to use in my project?